# How to create a non-wrapping text-span inside a TextView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a non-wrapping text span inside a TextView in my Android app.
What I've tried so far is to implement a `TextAppearanceSpan` and set the style of that span to:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.NonWrappingElement">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

...however, the text in the TextView is still wrapping..